# Trains connections between Cannes and Montpellier

Tags: trains, france, cannes

The train connection between Cannes and Montpellier seems to be A bit tricky.

There are trips with 2 or more trains changes. And then Ive found an intercitea for 30 euros only, every day at 16. Is it a good solution ?

Or do you suggest me another path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is so tricky about the trains from Cannes to Montpellier?

There are direct trains departing Cannes at 8:26, 12:27, 15:58, taking about 4 hours (all being trains from Nice to Bordeaux). At least between 12:00 and 18:00, there are several other connections with one or two changes and travel times between 4 and 5 hours. Be aware that if you change from a TGV to a regional train in Avignon (or vice versa), you have to plan a 10 minute bus trip between the two different stations "Avignon TGV" and "Avignon Centre".

Or is your question something completely else? You could easily have found this on any online train schedule search engine.

Comment: For "tricky" I meant indeed that I have to change 2 or more trains or either bus. But I needed an answer confirming it... thanks